# How to itetrate through files in a document library

Tags: development, document-library, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I've been creating a provider hosted app and I'm stuck at retrieving Documents titles using CSOM C# my code is as follows.

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            ClientOM.List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Response.Write(list.Title);

            Folder folder = list.RootFolder;
            clientContext.Load(folder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            string count = folder.ItemCount.ToString();
            Response.Write("Folder variable count: "+count);

            ClientOM.FileCollection fcollection = folder.Files;
            clientContext.Load(folder.Files);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Response.Write("\n Files count: " + folder.Files.Count);
            foreach (ClientOM.File f in folder.Files)
            {
                Response.Write(f.Title);


            }
}
```

Output :           Folder variable count: 6  Files count: 0

Comment: Is folder.files not returning files to you

Comment: @ateet Nope. I forgot ato add the output of this thing. I'll edit it and you can see what's going on there then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies. As i found that my code was right I started looking for some administrative aspect of the apps. One of my colleagues pointed out that the Provider hosted apps need some specific permisssions set.

I went to the Appmanifest.xml file and then I added this code.

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Comment: oho, Id didn't realize the you are doing this in app, definitely it need permission to access web to get files from document library

Answer (score 0):

Your are doing correct but instead of this code

```
ClientOM.FileCollection fcollection = folder.Files;
        clientContext.Load(folder.Files);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Response.Write("\n Files count: " + folder.Files.Count);
        foreach (ClientOM.File f in folder.Files)
        {
            Response.Write(f.Title);


        }
```

Try this code

```
 var files = folder.Files;
  clientContext.Load(files);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  Response.Write("\n Files count: " + files.Count);
       foreach (File f in files)
         {
           Response.Write(f.Title);  
         }
```

That should work!

Comment: tried that code but it's still the same output. I've checked id the document library actually has files too.

Comment: Do you have files at rootfolder? I mean files just in library without conatined in any folder. Are you trying to get files contained in folder within a library?

Comment: Yes I did. I found the answer to this which is evidently very frustrating.